# Detecting mean difference between two observed stochastic processes

Tags: gaussian-process, real-time

Suppose to collect real time two set of samples coming from two sources so defined:

S1: gaussian(m1, s1)

S2: gaussian(m1+m2, s1+s2) with probability p

S2: gaussian(m1, s1)       with probability 1-p

So there is (1-p) probability the two set of samples are collected from the same source and (p) probability they are not.

What test I can run online to detect such difference ?

Thanks.